# Determine WWID of LUN from mapped drive on Linux

Tags: linux, rhel, iscsi

I am trying to establish if there is an easier method to determine the WWID of an iSCSI LUN connected with a Linux Filesystem or mountpoint.

A frequent problem we have is where a user requests a disk expansion on a RHEL system with multiple iSCSI LUNs connected. A user will provide us with the path their LUN is mounted on, and from this we need to establish which LUN they are referring to so that we can make the increase as appropriate at the Storage side.

Currently we run `df -h` to get the Filesystem name, `pvdisplay` to get the VG Name and then `multipath -v4 -ll | grep "^mpath"` to get the WWID. This feels messy, long-winded and prone inconsistent interpretation.

Is there a more concise command we can run to determine the WWID of the device?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach.  The output format leaves something to be desired - it's more suited to eyeballs than programs.

`lsblk` understands the mapping of a mounted filesystem down through the LVM and multipath layers to the underlying block devices.  In the output below, `/dev/sdc` is my iSCSI-attached LUN, attached via one path to the target. It contains the volume group `vg1` and a logical volume `lv1`.  `/mnt/tmp` is where I have the filesystem on the LV mounted.

```
$ sudo lsblk
NAME                          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdc                                   8:32   0  128M  0 disk
└─360a010a0b43e87ab1962194c4008dc35 253:4    0  128M  0 mpath
  └─vg1-lv1                         253:3    0  124M  0 lvm   /mnt/tmp
```

At the 2nd level there is the SCSI WWN (`360a010...`), courtesy multipathd.